# How to localize c++/cmake program using GNU gettext

Tags: c++, cmake, gettext

Could you provide an example of GNU gettext usage to localize the following program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <libintl.h>

int main() {

  std::string name = "foo";

  std::cout << gettext(name) << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

assuming the following project structure?

```
project/
  main.cpp
  CMakeLists.txt
  lang/
    en_US.po
    de_DE.po
    fr_FR.po
    ru_RU.po
    ...
```

Existing guides are almost explicitly in C and really obscure. Also it is really unclear how to generate .pot files with the given project structure

### Edit

$ xgettext will generate empty file in this case.
Workaround:

```
// in main()
std::string_view name = gettext("foo");
std::cout << name << "\n";
```

Comment: the directory structure is important. It's `en_US/LC_MESSAGES`. `gettext(name)`?? `name is a `std::string`...

Comment: Just a note that the "workaround" here isn't a _workaround_, it's how gettext works. The `msgfmt` program that's used to generate the `.pot` files scans the source code and extracts the static strings inside each call. Imagine it's using a regexp, `/gettext\([^\)]*"(.*)"[^\)]*\)/` to scan the code. It'll only extract what's inside the quoted string as the message, since it doesn't parse your code and if it sees `gettext(name)`, it has no way to know what the value of `name` is. (Nor could it replace `name` with a translated string.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to generate .pot files

You write them by hand or generate with msginit. It's the same as `.po`, just a different name for documentation.

> Could you provide an example of GNU gettext usage to localize the following program

The following:

```
cat >./CMakeLists.txt <<EOF
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
project(trans)
include(CTest)
add_executable(main main.cpp)
file(GLOB ffs "lang/*.po")
set(TEXTDOMAIN myprogram)
make_directory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/locale)
foreach(ff IN LISTS ffs)
  get_filename_component(lang ${ff} NAME_WE)
  make_directory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/locale/${lang})
  make_directory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/locale/${lang}/LC_MESSAGES)
  add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT
      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/locale/${lang}/LC_MESSAGES/${TEXTDOMAIN}.mo
    DEPENDS
      ${ff}
    COMMAND msgfmt -o
      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/locale/${lang}/LC_MESSAGES/${TEXTDOMAIN}.mo
      ${ff}
  )
  add_custom_target(gen_${lang} ALL DEPENDS
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/locale/${lang}/LC_MESSAGES/${TEXTDOMAIN}.mo
  )
  add_test(NAME ${lang} COMMAND main)
  set_property(TEST ${lang} APPEND PROPERTY ENVIRONMENT
    TEXTDOMAINDIR=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/locale
    LANGUAGE=${lang}
  )
  set_tests_properties(${lang} PROPERTIES
    PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION "${lang} foo"
  )
endforeach()
EOF
```

```
cat >./main.cpp <<EOF
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <libintl.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <clocale>
int main() {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
        const char *textdomainstr = "myprogram";
        const char *textdomaindir = getenv("TEXTDOMAINDIR");
        if (textdomaindir) {
                bindtextdomain(textdomainstr, textdomaindir);
        }
        textdomain(textdomainstr);
        //
        std::string name = "foo";
        std::cout << gettext(name.c_str()) << "\n";
}
EOF
```

```
cat >./lang/de_DE.po <<EOF
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Last-Translator: Automatically generated\n"
"Language-Team: none\n"
"Language: de\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=3; plural=(n==1 ? 0 : n%10>=2 && n%10<=4 && (n%100<10 || n%100>=20) ? 1 : 2);\n"

msgid "foo"
msgstr "de_DE foo"

EOF

cat >./lang/en_US.po <<EOF
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Last-Translator: Automatically generated\n"
"Language-Team: none\n"
"Language: en\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=3; plural=(n==1 ? 0 : n%10>=2 && n%10<=4 && (n%100<10 || n%100>=20) ? 1 : 2);\n"

msgid "foo"
msgstr "en_US foo"

EOF

cat >./lang/pl_PL.po <<EOF
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Last-Translator: Automatically generated\n"
"Language-Team: none\n"
"Language: pl\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=3; plural=(n==1 ? 0 : n%10>=2 && n%10<=4 && (n%100<10 || n%100>=20) ? 1 : 2);\n"

msgid "foo"
msgstr "pl_PL foo"

EOF
```

Results in:

```
+ cmake -H. -B./_build --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=1 -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=1 -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=-Wall -ggdb3 -Wno-unused-function -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined -fsanitize=pointer-compare -fsanitize=pointer-subtract -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-Wall -ggdb3 -Wno-unused-function -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined -fsanitize=pointer-compare -fsanitize=pointer-subtract -DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=bin -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=lib -DCMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=lib -G Ninja
Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 12.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 12.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /dev/shm/.1000.home.tmp.dir/_build
+ cmake --build ./_build --parallel --verbose
[1/5] cd /dev/shm/.1000.home.tmp.dir/_build && msgfmt -o /dev/shm/.1000.home.tmp.dir/_build/locale/de_DE/LC_MESSAGES/myprogram.mo /dev/shm/.1000.home.tmp.dir/lang/de_DE.po
[2/5] cd /dev/shm/.1000.home.tmp.dir/_build && msgfmt -o /dev/shm/.1000.home.tmp.dir/_build/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/myprogram.mo /dev/shm/.1000.home.tmp.dir/lang/en_US.po
[3/5] cd /dev/shm/.1000.home.tmp.dir/_build && msgfmt -o /dev/shm/.1000.home.tmp.dir/_build/locale/pl_PL/LC_MESSAGES/myprogram.mo /dev/shm/.1000.home.tmp.dir/lang/pl_PL.po
[4/5] /usr/bin/c++   -Wall -ggdb3 -Wno-unused-function -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined -fsanitize=pointer-compare -fsanitize=pointer-subtract -MD -MT CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o -c /dev/shm/.1000.home.tmp.dir/main.cpp
[5/5] : && /usr/bin/c++ -Wall -ggdb3 -Wno-unused-function -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined -fsanitize=pointer-compare -fsanitize=pointer-subtract  CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o -o bin/main   && :
+ cd ./_build && ctest -V 
UpdateCTestConfiguration  from :/dev/shm/.1000.home.tmp.dir/_build/DartConfiguration.tcl
Parse Config file:/dev/shm/.1000.home.tmp.dir/_build/DartConfiguration.tcl
UpdateCTestConfiguration  from :/dev/shm/.1000.home.tmp.dir/_build/DartConfiguration.tcl
Parse Config file:/dev/shm/.1000.home.tmp.dir/_build/DartConfiguration.tcl
Test project /dev/shm/.1000.home.tmp.dir/_build
Constructing a list of tests
Done constructing a list of tests
Updating test list for fixtures
Added 0 tests to meet fixture requirements
Checking test dependency graph...
Checking test dependency graph end
test 1
    Start 1: de_DE

1: Test command: /dev/shm/.1000.home.tmp.dir/_build/bin/main
1: Working Directory: /dev/shm/.1000.home.tmp.dir/_build
1: Environment variables: 
1:  TEXTDOMAINDIR=/dev/shm/.1000.home.tmp.dir/_build/locale
1:  LANGUAGE=de_DE
1: Test timeout computed to be: 1500
1: de_DE foo
1/3 Test #1: de_DE ............................   Passed    0.01 sec
test 2
    Start 2: en_US

2: Test command: /dev/shm/.1000.home.tmp.dir/_build/bin/main
2: Working Directory: /dev/shm/.1000.home.tmp.dir/_build
2: Environment variables: 
2:  TEXTDOMAINDIR=/dev/shm/.1000.home.tmp.dir/_build/locale
2:  LANGUAGE=en_US
2: Test timeout computed to be: 1500
2: en_US foo
2/3 Test #2: en_US ............................   Passed    0.01 sec
test 3
    Start 3: pl_PL

3: Test command: /dev/shm/.1000.home.tmp.dir/_build/bin/main
3: Working Directory: /dev/shm/.1000.home.tmp.dir/_build
3: Environment variables: 
3:  TEXTDOMAINDIR=/dev/shm/.1000.home.tmp.dir/_build/locale
3:  LANGUAGE=pl_PL
3: Test timeout computed to be: 1500
3: pl_PL foo
3/3 Test #3: pl_PL ............................   Passed    0.01 sec

100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 3

Total Test time (real) =   0.04 sec
```

> how to generate .pot files with the given project structure

I always understood that `.pot` files are `.po` files. They are the same. You write them, or let `msginit` generate them from a template file, where this template file was also written by you, or generated by some script. I understood it's a hint in documentation like `msgmerge` that those are different files, like `.pot` has only one translation and `msgmerge` updates it in `.po` file.

You have to generate `.mo` files in proper `<lang>/LC_MESSAGES/<textdomain>.mo` directory and name structure.

Comment: At a glance it seems fine, but this CMake file does not generate /lang/main.pot (or similar) initial file; also i'm struggling with xgettext usage, as it generates a file without any strings for translation

Comment: I do not understand your comment. `At a glance it seems fine` what seems not fine at not a glance? `CMake file does not generate /lang/main.pot (or similar) initial file` ? Why would it? What is the "main.pot initial file"? `also i'm struggling with xgettext usage, as it generates a file without any strings for translation` Sure you are, `xgettext` is for `gettext("A CONSTANT STRING")`, not for parsing C++ code.

Comment: GNU Manual: "When starting a new translation, the translator creates a file called LANG.po, as a copy of the package.pot template file with modifications in the initial comments (at the beginning of the file) and in the header entry (the first entry, near the beginning of the file)." I assume CMake is able to create this .pot file

Comment: Yes, _you_ as the maintainer of a program, provide the template file for other translators to wirte translations. You write the file by hand, or generate with for example xgettext. It's the same file with just `msgstr ""` empty stuff to fill. Like https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/master/po/util-linux.pot . The code you posted, as you noticed, is not compatible with xgettext. Chagne the code to be `gettext("foo")` or write your own generator, or do by hand.

Comment: That's what i'm struggnig with, because xgettext is not working for me as it generates the empty template file

Comment: ? Yes, because `xgettext` is not for `gettext(some code)`, but for `gettext("some constant string")`. It's a simple crude regex parser. Really, `gettext()` should be used always with constant strings anyway, but your code had `std::string`.